# Why is the Surface Toolkit demanding an Application?

Tags: wpf, surface-toolkit

I'm trying to use Surface Toolkit controls on WPF controls in a WPF Control Library. I'm using these controls in a MFC front using HwndSource. All of that is fine. The problem I have is that now I get the following exception:

> A System.Windows.Application is required.  Please initialize an Application before using this API.
>
> at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.SurfaceMetrics..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.SurfaceMetrics.get_Instance()
>      at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.DefaultColorSource..ctor(Int32 rank)
>      at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.SurfaceColors..ctor()
>      at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.SurfaceColors.EnsureInstance()
>      at Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.SurfaceColors.get_ControlForegroundBrushKey()

Comment: what happened to the `var app = new App();`?

Comment: Yup that was my solution. :) I just had to do it in MFC instead. I changed my WPF application into a Class Library, and thus had to get rid of App.Xaml. It was painful but this way things are cleaner.

Comment: I didn't know I could new up an Application. I thought it had to be a subclass of Application. If you want put it as your answer and I'll give you cred. It was your original answer, after all. LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to new up an instance of `System.Windows.Application` in my MFC application. That pacified the Surface Toolkit.

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18766442/how-do-i-resize-a-wpf-control-inside-a-cwnd) for my complete WPF in MFC solution. It's pretty marvelous, I have to say. Way better than it was in the old days.